# Unable to instantiate class because of constructor

Tags: java

I'm working on a sort of package scanning.  This is probably not the best route, but I the solutions I found on Google seemed to do a whole lot more than what I need.

I'm struggling to instantiate a class and it's driving me nuts.  Here's my code to instantiate:

```
    String[] packageList = {
        getPackageName(),
        "com.socket.event.handler"
    };
    for (String packageListName : packageList) {
        try {
            String className = this.getType(); // getDashboard
            className = className.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + className.substring(1)+"Handler"; //GetDashboardHandler
            clazz = Class.forName(packageListName+"."+className) //shows correct package/class name
                    .asSubclass(EventHandler.class);

            return (EventHandler) clazz.getConstructor(clazz.getClass()).newInstance(getData());
            //return (EventHandler) clazz.newInstance();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            //swallow, this is ok
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The `getData()` used there looks like this:
    public HashMap getData() {
        return data;
    }

The class being instantiated is:

```
public class GetDashboardHandler extends EventHandler<GetDashboardHandler> {
    public String workstationUuid;

    public GetDashboardHandler() {
        super();
    }

    public GetDashboardHandler(HashMap<String, Object> data) {
        super(data, GetDashboardHandler.class);
    }
```

I have a default constructor and one that with parameters to meet the specific need.  I'm still seeing this exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.socket.event.handler.GetDashboardHandler.<init>(java.lang.Class)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2730)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1676)
    at com.socket.SocketMessage.getEventHandler(SocketMessage.java:88)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
clazz.getConstructor(clazz.getClass())
```

It means that you are looking for a constructor that is defined as:

```
public GetDashboardHandler(Class data) {
```

But you want a HashMap as parameter:

```
clazz.getConstructor(HashMap.class)
```